# AllowOverride None when parent directory has AllowOverride All

Tags: apache-2.4

I have the following Apache 2.4 configuration:

```
<Directory "/home/myuser/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/myuser/public_html/uploads">
    AllowOverride None
    php_flag engine off
</Directory>
```

The uploads folder are uploads done by users. I want to disable any chance of someone uploading a .htaccess file and changing the php_flag.

Unfortunately if i create a .htaccess file in /home/myuser/public_html/uploads/subfolder, I can override the php_flag. For some reason, AllowOverride None is not working.

Am i doing something wrong? What could cause this behavior?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sure you reloaded/restarted apache after changing configuration?

Comment: Yes, I even did a full restart thinking that a reload wouldn't work.